# How to open mp3 file on phone's default app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My code is, at the moment like this:

When the user clicks on an audio file in my file manager, it should open it on their default audio app, but the file manager app just crashes. It also happens with apk and pdf files, but I removed those from the code to focus on the mp3 problem.

Also, if anyone knows a universal way to open files without specifying an extension, it would be amazing!

Thanks in advance, my friends.

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            if (files[position].toString().contains(".png") || files[position].toString().contains(".jpg") || files[position].toString().contains(".jpeg")) {
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(files[position].toString()), "image/jpeg");
                            } else if (files[position].toString().contains(".mp4")) {
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(files[position].toString()), "video/*");
                            } else if (files[position].toString().contains(".mp3")) {
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(files[position].toString()), "audio/*");
                            } else if (files[position].toString().contains(".doc") || files[position].toString().contains(".docx")) {
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(files[position].toString()), "application/msword");
                            } else {
                                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(files[position].toString()), "*/*");
                            }
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you did in the code, but if you have the uri to the mp3 file, just use intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

edit: I checked my codebase for a use like this, I opened a txt file for an import. Setting a type always crashed the app for me, hence I set the type to "* /*". See below for a similar code that works.

```
public void importDictionary() {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*"); //needed to not make it crash
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
```

Override onActivityResult for action afterwards

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: It crashes with any file if I use this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent like this,

```js
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The app keeps crashing once I try to open an mp3 file, even with this code.